# laravel/horizon - configure number of processes on initial start

Tags: laravel, queue, horizon

By default laravel/horizon is starting `maxProcesses` on initial start.
In our environment the new queue is empty until we activate it, so we would prefer an initial boot with the number of `minProcesses` to reduce the resource usage.

Is it possible to configure horizon like this ? Or does anyone know how to achieve this goal ?